# Trying to convert a base64String into a IFormFile throws SystemInvalidOperation exception in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, base64, iformfile

I'm trying to convert a list of base64String into a list of IFormFile. When I try `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)` I got a `stream.ReadTimeout SystemInvalidOperation`. So Why it isn't working?

Here is my code:

```
private async Task<List<IFormFile>> Base64ToImage(List<EquipmentFile> equipmentFiles)
{
    List<IFormFile> formFiles = new List<IFormFile>();
    foreach (var eqp in equipmentFiles)
    {
      byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(eqp.File);
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
      IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, bytes.Length, eqp.Name, eqp.Name);
      formFiles.Add(file);
    }
    return formFiles;
}
```

My Stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
   at FieldService.CallCenter.Api.Controllers.EquipmentLibraryController.Base64ToImage(List`1 equipmentFiles) in C:\Users\CMTech-DEV\Documents\cmtech\fieldservice-api\src\CallCenter\FieldService.CallCenter.API\Controllers\EquipmentLibraryController.cs:line 331
   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
   at FieldService.CallCenter.Api.Controllers.EquipmentLibraryController.Base64ToImage(List`1 equipmentFiles) in C:\Users\CMTech-DEV\Documents\cmtech\fieldservice-api\src\CallCenter\FieldService.CallCenter.API\Controllers\EquipmentLibraryController.cs:line 331
```

Comment: Provide a proper stack trace

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, but you are disposing all of the streams before you return them (wrapped by FormFile) via the `using`. Unless FormFile makes a copy of the stream then this is likely bad and could be related

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are implicitly calling `Dispose` on the `MemoryStream`s after you pass them to the `FormFile` constructor due to the `using` block. You then return a list of `FormFile` objects where the inner streams are all **disposed**.

`FormFile` does not make a copy of the stream's content, but instead (via [`ReferencedReadStream`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a598360d1963b8f1dce7f3064da9f8ce1c7061df/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/ReferenceReadStream.cs#L104)) calls methods like `Stream.Read` which (in the case of `MemoryStream` at least) will [throw an exception if the stream has been closed](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs#L350)--which it has due to `Dispose`.

You've not provided any information such as a stack trace so this is a best guess, but removing the `using` block *should* suffice to fix this problem.

```
private List<IFormFile> Base64ToImage(List<EquipmentFile> equipmentFiles)
{
    List<IFormFile> formFiles = new List<IFormFile>();
    foreach (var eqp in equipmentFiles)
    {
        
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(eqp.File);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        
        IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, bytes.Length, eqp.Name, eqp.Name);
        formFiles.Add(file);
        
    }
    return formFiles;
}
```

Comment: [`FormFile`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a598360d1963b8f1dce7f3064da9f8ce1c7061df/src/Http/Http/src/FormFile.cs#L15) is a strange class.  It doesn't dispose the `_baseStream` itself and doesn't provide any methods for consumers to dispose it, either by implementing `IDisposable` itself or providing a getter to let the consumer dispose the `_baseStream`.  I don't think it is mean for general use.

Comment: @dbc I think you are right. What's interesting is that in ASP.NET (not Core), `FormFile` was in an [`Internal` namespace](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/FormFile.cs) yet publicly accessible. There was usually a reason for this pattern, typically for "advanced" cases or because other parts of the infrastructure needed access.

Comment: I removed the `using` block but the problem remains. I also provided a stack trace. Should I add my controller method?